# O que é "síntese de lauda"

Tags: significado

Solicitaram-me uma **Síntese de Lauda**, porem não tenho ideia do que é isso, pesquisei e apenas encontrei termos bem técnicos explicando o que é, e tive dificuldade de entendimento. Alguém tem um explicação simples para isso?

Comment: Pode explicar melhor o contexto? Será que não te pediram para escrever uma síntese (de algum texto), com tamanho limitado a uma lauda?

Comment: Provável que tenha sido isso.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lauda, substantivo feminino, corresponde a uma certa quantidade de texto impresso.

> A **[lauda de jornal e editora](http://www.sintra.org.br/site/?p=c&id=36&codcat=22)** (papel "tamanho ofício") tem tradicionalmente, de 30 a 32 linhas com até 72 caracteres (um "caractere" - termo usado em computação e legendagem de filmes, além das áreas de que estamos tratando - é qualquer letra, símbolo ou espaço digitado).

Um tradutor geralmente recebe o seu pagamento pelo número de laudas que o texto original vai ocupar.  "O senhor vai traduzir este capítulo do livro.  Acredito que isso vai ocupar umas 25 laudas." (lauda é a folha de papel digitada ou datilografada pelo tradutor, pelo repórter, jornalista ou autor.)

- O significado de "síntese de lauda" depende do contexto.  Em telejornalismo pode referir-se a um resumo do que contem a lauda com a informação a ser transmitida pelo reporter.